# Fine way to improve and tuning these models Sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I am building an algorithm to predict football matches for sport betting.
I have a function that train some models from a `list`, I would improve the accuracy of models and get the probabilities as accurate as possible.

List of classifiers

```
  clf1 = LogisticRegression(multi_class='multinomial', random_state=1)
  clf2 = GradientBoostingClassifier()
  clf3 = MLPClassifier()

  classifiers=[
    MLPClassifier(),
    VotingClassifier(estimators=[('lr', clf1), ('rf', clf2), ('gnb', clf3)], voting='soft'),
    AdaBoostClassifier(),
    GradientBoostingClassifier(),
    CalibratedClassifierCV(),
    LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(),
    LogisticRegression(),
    LogisticRegressionCV(),
    QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis(),
  ]
```

Code

```
def proba_classifiers(df_clean, df_clean_pred, X, X_pred, y, classifier_list):

    df_proba=[]
    df_proba_pred=[]
    for classifier in classifier_list:
        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.8, stratify=y)
        classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

        p_train = classifier.predict(X_train)
        acc_train = accuracy_score(y_train, p_train)
        p_test = classifier.predict(X_test)
        acc_test = accuracy_score(y_test, p_test)

        print(f'Accuracy Train: {"{:.0%}".format(acc_train)}, Accuracy Test: {"{:.0%}".format(acc_test)}, Model: {classifier.__class__.__name__} ')

        proba = classifier.predict_proba(X)
        proba_pred = classifier.predict_proba(X_pred)
        proba = pd.DataFrame(proba, columns=['H','D','A'])
        df_proba.append(proba)
        proba_pred = pd.DataFrame(proba_pred, columns=['H','D','A'])
        df_proba_pred.append(proba_pred)

    df_proba = pd.concat(df_proba,axis=1)

    #adjust iloc
    df_clean = df_clean.iloc[:, :16]
    df_proba = pd.concat([df_clean.reset_index(drop=True), df_proba], axis=1)
    
    df_proba_pred = pd.concat(df_proba_pred,axis=1)

    #adjust iloc
    df_clean_pred = df_clean_pred.iloc[:, :16]
    df_proba_pred = pd.concat([df_clean_pred.reset_index(drop=True), df_proba_pred], axis=1)

    return df_proba, df_proba_pred
```

PS `X_pred` is X that I want to predict.

Models score

```
Accuracy Train: 48%, Accuracy Test: 48%, Model: MLPClassifier 
Accuracy Train: 48%, Accuracy Test: 48%, Model: VotingClassifier 
Accuracy Train: 48%, Accuracy Test: 48%, Model: AdaBoostClassifier 
Accuracy Train: 50%, Accuracy Test: 48%, Model: GradientBoostingClassifier 
Accuracy Train: 48%, Accuracy Test: 48%, Model: CalibratedClassifierCV 
Accuracy Train: 48%, Accuracy Test: 48%, Model: LinearDiscriminantAnalysis 
Accuracy Train: 48%, Accuracy Test: 48%, Model: LogisticRegression 
Accuracy Train: 48%, Accuracy Test: 48%, Model: LogisticRegressionCV 
Accuracy Train: 47%, Accuracy Test: 47%, Model: QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis
```

Comment: What you are dong here is not necessarily looking to "improve" a model. What you are doing is testing different models to see which would be the best algorithm to use. With that, you should split the data set after each iteration. Each split will be different, so when comparing the algorithms, you're not getting a true "apples to apples" comparison. Secondly, something seem a bit off in that you get all the same accuracy for everything. Can you share your dataset?

Comment: I'm also confused by what parameters you are feeding into the function. You only need  X,  y, and the classifier_list

Comment: Yes, so to compare the models I have to split the dataset equal for each split. I add `random_state` in `train_test_split` function to solve this, right?

Comment: Here is the dataset https://filebin.net/6kw8mx26ywfqad6t

Comment: `df_clean` and `df_clean_pred` are the original dataset without features where I `concat` probabilities of each model.

Comment: yes, including the random_state should take care of that. Or you can just split the dat 1 time, before going into the loop

Comment: Can you share then the `df_clean` `df_clean_pred` and `X_pred`?

Comment: Here all the files https://filebin.net/6kw8mx26ywfqad6t

Answer (score 0):

I want to assume you want to increase your accuracy, most times if you want to increase your accuracy you will probably need to use GridSearch in sklearn. This is a way of tuning your model(classifier) to increase the accuracy, you can go through the documentation link below to learn more.
After you finishing turning it gives you the best parameters to fix into your classifier.
For example where you have "clf1 = LogisticRegression(multi_class='multinomial', random_state=1)"

You will need more parameters such as I have defined in the code below.

[Sklearn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html?highlight=logistic%20regression%20gridsearch)

However here is a way to do Logistic regression hypertunning but search for others like adaboost and the rest for best parameters:

```
# Hyperparameter tunning for logistic regression
logreg_grid = {"C": np.logspace(-5, 5, 10),
              "solver": ["liblinear","lbfgs"], 
               "tol":np.logspace(-5, 5, 10),
               "max_iter":np.arange(100, 3000,80),
               "class_weight": [None, {0:1, 0:1.5}, {0:1, 1:2}]}

# setup grid hyperparameter search for logistic resgression
gs_logreg = GridSearchCV(LogisticRegression(),
                               param_grid=logreg_grid,
                               cv=5,
                               verbose=True)
# fit grid hyperparamter search model
gs_logreg.fit(Xtrain,ytrain)
```

After you have done that you can use this code to get the parameters and fix into your classifier:

```
gs_logreg.best_params_
```

Then fix the parameters into your earlier equation, only if you have done the hypertuning.

```
clf1 = LogisticRegression(C=2154.4346900318865, solver='rbf', tol=0.0037649358067924714, max_iter = "300", multi_class='multinomial', random_state=1)
```